# Cordova FileTransfer plugin set to allow any mime type

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the file transfer plugin to upload images from the device to the server. The default mimeType is `mimeType: "image/jpeg",` . But the images will have different extensions. How do I set this to allow any kind of image.

The problem is that it breaks if the image is not a jpg extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change

`mimeType: "multipart/form-data"`

It will allow to select different types of image.

Comment: But this will also allow uploading any othe doc files like .ppt,.exe, .doc and so on ...